# Improve jquery function to show/hide sections depending on day of the week not working in IE8?

Tags: jquery, cross-browser

I have the following function to hide/show sections of a webpage depending of the day of the week.

Unfortunately I found out that this is not working on IE8 and displays all days remaining including current day of the week.

it works on Chrome,Safari,Firefox, IE7, IE9 and IE10 but not in IE 8.

Anyone that can help?

See function below.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            var dayOfWeek = new Date().getDay();


            if (dayOfWeek == 2) {
                $("#menu1").css("display", "none");
                $("#menu2").css("display", "block");
                $("#menu3").css("display", "none");
                $("#menu4").css("display", "none");
                $("#menu5").css("display", "none");
            }
            else if (dayOfWeek == 3) {
                $("#menu1").css("display", "none");
                $("#menu2").css("display", "none");
                $("#menu3").css("display", "block");
                $("#menu4").css("display", "none");
                $("#menu5").css("display", "none");
            }
            else if (dayOfWeek == 4) {
                $("#menu1").css("display", "none");
                $("#menu2").css("display", "none");
                $("#menu3").css("display", "none");
                $("#menu4").css("display", "block");
                $("#menu5").css("display", "none");
            }
            else if (dayOfWeek == 5) {
                $("#menu1").css("display", "none");
                $("#menu2").css("display", "none");
                $("#menu3").css("display", "none");
                $("#menu4").css("display", "none");
                $("#menu5").css("display", "block");
            }
            else {

                $("#menu1").css("display", "block");
                $("#menu2").css("display", "none");
                $("#menu3").css("display", "none");
                $("#menu4").css("display", "none");
                $("#menu5").css("display", "none");

            }



        });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Figure out what's not working. Is it an error? Is IE not returning the day of the week properly? Is it a CSS problem?

Comment: You should provide jsfiddle as well.

Comment: Do this on server side will be better ? :D

Comment: I do not get an error anywhere, let me provide example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
I have made small jsfiddle using your code. Please check below demo.
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q6gtS/9/